# Using Duration to check if hours between two days are still within Duration

Tags: java, date, java-time, duration, date-manipulation

I was working with LocalDateTime and trying to see if the purchase date(in my case) is withing last x units(days/hours)

I achieved this the following way

```
 public static final int BOOK_PURCHASED_MIN_HOURS = 72;
 private boolean isWithinAllowedMinTime(LocalDateTime purchaseDateTime) {
    return !LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusHours(BOOK_PURCHASED_MIN_HOURS ).isAfter(purchaseDateTime);
  }
```

This works perfectly fine and gives me true or false if the book has been purchase in 72 hours

I was wondering something like this can be done but with Duration in java where I do not have to worry about time unit and simply can specify like PT03D or PT72H

Comment: Yes. Just use [`LocalDateTime.minus(TemporalAmount)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minus-java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount-).

Comment: Only using `LocalDateTime` for a point in time is ill-advised. If your dates and times are always in UTC, use `OffsetDateTime` for them, or `Instant`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering something like this can be done but with Duration in
> java where I do not have to worry about time unit and simply can
> specify like PT03D or PT72H

Of course, you can do so. You can pass a duration string to your function and parse it to a `Duration` object to perform a calculation based on it.

I also recommend you use `OffsetDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime` so that you can use the same offset with [`OffsetDateTime#now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-).

**Demo**:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests    
        System.out.println(isWithinAllowedMinTime(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusHours(50), "PT72H")); // true
        System.out.println(isWithinAllowedMinTime(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusHours(75), "PT72H")); // false
        System.out.println(isWithinAllowedMinTime(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusHours(50), "P3DT12H")); // true
        System.out.println(isWithinAllowedMinTime(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusHours(72), "P3DT12H")); // true
        System.out.println(isWithinAllowedMinTime(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusHours(90), "P3DT12H")); // false
    }

    static boolean isWithinAllowedMinTime(OffsetDateTime purchaseDateTime, String strDuration) {
        Duration duration = Duration.parse(strDuration);
        return !OffsetDateTime.now(purchaseDateTime.getOffset()).minus(duration).isAfter(purchaseDateTime);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
true
false
true
true
false
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own utility where you can specify time interval as "3d" for 3 days "72h" for 72 hours and so on. This utility is part of Open Source MgntUtils Java library written and maintained by me. Here is a code to demonstrate the point:

```
private static final String BOOK_PURCHASED_MIN_INTERVAL = "72h"; //possible values could be like "3d" for 3 days
private static void timeIntervalTest() {
    TimeInterval bookPurchesedMinInterval = TextUtils.parseStringToTimeInterval(BOOK_PURCHASED_MIN_INTERVAL);
    ZonedDateTime purchaseDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now().minusHours(71);  //This is to simulate your parameter of book purchacing date
    long seconds = ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond() - purchaseDateTime.toEpochSecond();
    System.out.println(seconds > bookPurchesedMinInterval.toSeconds());
}
```

Here is Javadoc for [TextUtils.parseStringToTimeInterval()](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html#parseStringToTimeInterval-java.lang.String-) method. If you want to use the library you can get it it as [maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (source code and Javadoc included). Here is the link for full [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/)

Comment: That looks like a detour to me. We don’t want to calculate in seconds (or some other time unit) when we can leave the calculations to our date-time objects and not care which units they use internally. And it even requires a 3rd party dependency. Thanks, but thanks no.